# Putting a group structure on a set by identifying it with a subgroup of transformations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose I forgot what addition was on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I could recreate it with the following line of thinking, which is kind of "groupifying" a set: shift my perspective from "points" $(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$ to certain *transformations* of the plane: the ones that take a fixed reference point $\vec{0}$ to $(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$ (by just translating the whole space). Then I define a group operation by taking $\vec{a} + \vec{b}$ to be the result of applying the *transformation* $\vec{b}$ to the *point* $\vec{a}$.

Similarly, if I think of the set of frames on $\mathbb{R}^n$, I shift my perspective from frames $\vec{a}_1, \dotsc, \vec{a}_n$ to the *transformations* that take a fixed reference frame $\vec{e}_1, \dotsc, \vec{e}_n$ to $\vec{a}_1, \dotsc, \vec{a}_n$. Now I define a group operation $\vec{a}_1, \dotsc, \vec{a}_n \odot \vec{b}_1, \dotsc, \vec{b}_n$ as follows: take the transformation corresponding to the $b_i$, and apply it to the $a_j$'s, one by one.

Another way to look at it: the transformations already naturally form a group which act on my set, and I am specifying an embedding of $G$-sets between the points and the $G$-set $|G|$, which gives my set a group structure. 
[image]

Bottom line is I'm looking for comments on this thought, or perhaps a reference that goes more deeply into it.

If you want a specific question, it would be: is this somehow more profound than these examples might suggest? Is it simpler than they suggest, once I pass to the correct level of abstraction? Has this been tamed with a name?

Comment: Just for another example: If I recall, Hatcher uses a idea a bit like this in his Algebraic Topology book when he sets up the multiplicative structure of the free group. Rather than define a multiplication on the set of reduced words $W$ directly (as something like concatenation followed by reduction), he instead defines a map $L_g : G \to G$ for each generator, and constructs the free group as a group of *transformations* of $W$. I think there is nothing extremely deep about this example, though. It is more a clever labour saving device (makes group axioms easier to verify).

Comment: How do you define what a transformation of the plane is without first knowing how to add numbers?

Comment: @StefanPerko Just translating the whole space by a given vector. By that I mean not an algebraic definition, but a geometric definition.

Comment: I still don't see how you can actually formalize this without formalizing addition of reals along the way.

Comment: @StefanPerko If I have the square $[-1,1] \times [-1,1] \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, and I tell you to rotate it $90^\circ$, would you consider that a well-defined operation on vectors, independent of whether I know how to calculate it?